# strtotime outputs nothing

Tags: php

I tried the following

```
echo "Pre order date > $pre_order_close_date";
$pre_order_unix_time = strtotime($pre_order_close_date);    
echo "Unix time is > $pre_order_unix_time";
```

The result is

```
Pre order date >  31 Jan 2016Unix time is >
```

I then tried the following to see if my date format is fine

```
echo "Pre order date > $pre_order_close_date";
$pre_order_unix_time = strtotime("31 Jan 2016");    
echo "Unix time is > $pre_order_unix_time";
```

The result return was

```
Pre order date >  31 Jan 2016Unix time is > 1454198400
```

It seems that if I input the string directly its working fine, but if I use a variable in place of 31 Jan 2016, it does not output anything.

What could I have do wrong here.

**Thanks for helping!**

** How I get my pre_order_close_date **

$get_content is of this value

```
<p>Retail Price: USD 42<br />
<span class="il">Pre</span>&#8211;<span class="il">Order</span> Price: USD 40<br />
<span class="il">Pre</span>&#8211;<span class="il">Order</span> <span class="il">Close</span> <span class="il">Date</span>: 31 Jan 2016<br />
Release <span class="il">Date</span>: 1Q 2016</p>
$get_content_explode = explode("\n",$get_content);

foreach($get_content_explode as $gce)
{
if(strstr(strtolower($gce),"close"))
{
$pre_order_close_arr = explode(":",$gce);
$pre_order_close_date = trim($pre_order_close_arr[1]);
}//end if gce
}//end foreach
```

Comment: I suspect `$pre_order_close_date` contains some HTML markup. You don't see it when you view the web page. Try using View Source to see what's really there.

Comment: Works fine here: http://ideone.com/uB3V5e

Comment: @Barmar how do I ensure the text I see will be convert as string for php, so that my  strtotime will works.

Comment: You need to fix whatever you're using to set the variable in the first place.

Comment: Where does the variable come from? I notice that you printed an extra space after `>` -- does it begin with something like `&nbsp;`?

Comment: No i use it to display the output, the weird thing is my strtotime doesn't return anything, I tried var_dump it give me a false0

Comment: Please show how you're setting `$pre_order_close_date`.

Comment: I tried to var_dump my pre_order_close_date it returns string(13) " 31 Jan 2016"

Comment: @Barmar, my_pre_order_close date is obtain from explode a string (updated my question)

Comment: It still works for me: http://ideone.com/uB3V5e

Comment: How are you setting `$get_content`? I suspect there's something in there that you don't know about. Maybe it's `Pre-Order Close Date:&nbsp;31 Jan 2016`.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question code from view source perspective. I fetching it from wordpress editor and this the html markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$get_content` contains HTML markup. Use `strip_tags()` to remove it.

```
$get_content_explode = explode("\n", str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', (strip_tags($get_content))));
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/lsW4CQ)

Comment: I dont know why but it still doesn't work on my end, any chance to debug or see error log for such issue?

Comment: Try `var_dump(htmlentities($get_content))` to see everything in `$get_content`.

Comment: string(17) " 31 Jan 2016" if I var dump $pre_order_close_date

Comment: if I var dump get_content, it return me the same thing, just without explode yet.

Comment: I told you to use `htmlentities()` so you can see all the markup in the variables.

Comment: string(17) "&nbsp;31 Jan 2016"

Comment: I tried $pre_order_close_date = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$pre_order_close_date);

but it doesn't remove away the &nbsp;

Comment: I can't explain that. You must have done something wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `str_replace`, and tested it in the demo.

Comment: thats &nbsp; seems to unable remove, i used your code.

Comment: If i use $pre_order_close_date = substr($pre_order_close_date,2);
 its work , but if i use string_replace &nbsp it doesn't work

Comment: That makes no sense. `&nbsp;` is more than 2 characters.

Comment: Maybe instead of the `&nbsp;` entity, you have a literal Unicode non-breaking space in the string (code point 0160).